# How to view differences between config file and real resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

i've created a kubernetes cluster using kops and  its config file in S3.

The problem is that i've modified some resources manually (such as ec2 properties).

I would like to know if there is some way to view the changes i've made manually.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is kops 
 terraform output https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/terraform.md (`--target=terraform` flag). Then

1. Create a cluster via terraform
2. Do smth manually
3. Run `terraform plan`. This will show the diff between current and config. Either hit `apply` to revert manual changes, or code manual changes and re-apply.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have used AWS config service for auditing the configurations of your AWS resources, you can view the changes either by  AWS Config console or by using  AWS CLI.

Please refer [Viewing Configuration Details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/view-manage-resource-console.html) to see the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `kubediff` from weaveworks.

https://github.com/weaveworks/kubediff